# Dynamically insert variables into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making charts for my app and I've experienced problem with dynamic variables. The variable for one single line on the chart looks like:

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  type: 'scatter'
};
```

**It has to look like this**:

```
[
 var trace1 = {
   x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
   y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
   type: 'scatter'
 }, 
 var trace1 = {
   x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
   y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
   type: 'scatter'
 }
]
```

But it has to be dynamic: I will ask server for the amount of lines. And the problem now is to make as many `trace[i]` variables as the server says. For example, if the response is 3, it has to make three variables:

```
trace1 = {}, trace2 = {}, trace3 = {}
```

And it has to be inside array:

```
[trace1 = {}, trace2 = {}, trace3 = {}]
```

**My question** is:  it is even possible to do something like this? A loop which will make for example there 3 variables in an array?

This is my goal:

```
[trace1 = {}, trace2 = {}, trace3 = {}]
```

Comment: Do you need them to be named? If not, just inserting the objects into the array would work. Otherwise, you can use an Object instead, and generate the keys dynamically, and set the value as the array of objects

Comment: @Abdul They have to be named, because in the legend will appear the name of each data-line.

Comment: Arrays do not contain "variables". They contain "values". The values do not have names, unless you consider the indices (0, 1, 2...) a kind of name.

Comment: *it has to be inside array* Who said? Why? Who is consuming this? *look at the example how it has to look.* Your example is a malformed JS object. You can't create something like that in JS.

Comment: Your goal doesn't make much sense. Why don't you show us real examples of what the server returns and what your chart expects. What you've shown is not possible with JavaScript.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That's all what I wanted. It's not possible. Thank you.

Comment: @H.Doe What you've shown is not possible. What your charting component needs likely is possible, but you seem to be reticent on what exactly that is.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yeah thats why I've thank you, because I was likely sure that its not possible and u just made me 100% sure  that I have to bite that problem from another side.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to ask a different question that invalidates existing answers. If you have a different question to ask, ask a new question. I've rolled back your question to its previous form. You can always close/delete your own question if you feel it is necessary.

Comment: *bite that problem* You haven't told us **what** problem that is. Presumably you have a library which requires an input in some form. What form is that? To whom will you be passing this object that you are trying to create?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object instead of an array, and then iterate through the keys, as you would an array:

```js
traces = {};

for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
 var thisTrace = {
      x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
      type: 'scatter'
    };

  traces["trace" + i] = thisTrace;
}

console.log(traces); // all the traces
console.log(traces["trace1"]); // access the "trace1" object

for (var traceName in traces) {
    // traceName is the key
    // traces[traceName] is the trace object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean but it you want an object like you refer in the desired result and you've the variables already defined, you could do someting like :

```
var nbr_of_objects = 3;
var traces_result = {};

for(var i=1;i<=nbr_of_objects;i++){
  traces_result["trace"+i] = window["trace"+i];
}
```

Hope this help.

```js
var trace1 = {x: [1],y: [10],type: 'scatter'};
var trace2 = {x: [1, 2],y: [10, 15],type: 'scatter'};
var trace3 = {x: [1, 2, 3],y: [10, 15, 1],type: 'scatter'};

var nbr_of_objects = 3;
var traces_result = {};

for(var i=1;i<=nbr_of_objects;i++){
  traces_result["trace"+i] = window["trace"+i];
}

console.log(traces_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not appropriate solution**

Since you can store it in an object, you can set the name as array key

```
var traces = {};
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  traces["trace"+(i+1)] = {
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
    type: 'scatter'
  }
}
```

then you could access the variable with the array's index like `traces["trace1"]` or `traces.trace1` or to iterate over it like this:

```
for(var key in traces){
  console.log(traces[key])
}
```

**Appropriate solution**

```
var traces = [];
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  traces.push({
    name:"trace"+(i+1),
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
    type: 'scatter'
  });
}
```

You should iterate over the array looking for the matching trace name property instead of using its names as the array's key and use a for in like:

```
for(var i=0; i < traces.length; i++){
  console.log(traces[i].name);
}
```

Comment: He needs them to be named

Comment: Got it now, Thanks

Comment: for loop over an object is an anti-pattern use for in and check if it is property http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Comment: The user asked for a solution with dynamic variables inside a array... of course it will be a anti pattern.

Comment: The other possible solution would be a `eval()`, unsafe, or `window['var'+num]`, not so good but safer than eval(), in conjunction with a `array.push()`.